# Different actions for different causes of end editing

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield

I have a tableview with two textfields in each cell. My intended behavior is that the user can either drag the tableview to end editing or press Return to advance to the next cell/textfield. I have been trying to use the `textFieldShouldReturn` and `textfieldDidEndEditing` methods, however, I am unable to determine in the `EndEditing` method what the cause of end editing was.

Should I be using some other method to determine that a `textfield` will end editing due to a drag?

Comment: textFieldDidEndEditing returns the textField. In that you could use the textFIeld.tag to identify the field that had just ended. In your drag detection code call endEditing:YES. So, if it's your textField that triggered it, you can check if if has the tag of the textField, otherwise it's the drag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you need a trigger when the table view is dragged. User this method from `UITableViewDelegate`

```
func scrollViewWillBeginDragging(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    yourTextField.resignFirstResponder()
}
```

Now, you need to find your text field in this delegate method. I will just give you a hint on this. Since each cell has the textfield, in your `cellForRow` method, simply set your textfield's tag to be `indexPath.row`. Then in this delegate method, you can find our your cell and textfield by index number.

Comment: Thank you this is basically what I ended up doing